# Android FirebaseRecyclerView with GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with FirebaseRecyclerView. It only works with StaggeredGridLayoutManager and not with GridLayoutManager, and I don't really know why. Here is my minimum code on the Fragment (I use a bottom navigation bar which change the fragment):

```
public class xFragment extends Fragment{
 //...
 ...//
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

   mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3);

    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("some_list");   


    modelRecyclerview = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.grid);
    modelRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
    modelRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);

    mFirebaseModelAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model,ModelViewHolder>
            (Model.class, R.layout.grid_image, ModelViewHolder.class,
                    mDatabaseRef) {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ModelViewHolder viewHolder,
                                          Model model, int position) {
            viewHolder.bindModel(model);
        }
    };
    modelRecyclerview.setAdapter(mFirebaseModelAdapter);
    Log.i(TAG,"Creation Success");
    return view;
}
}
```

And my view holder code:

```
public class ModelViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

private static final String TAG = ModelViewHolder.class.getSimpleName();
public ImageView thumbnailImage;
private Context mContext;

public ModelViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    thumbnailImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumb_image);
    mContext = itemView.getContext();
}

public void bindModel(Model firebaseNode) {

    StorageReference storageReference =  FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(myBucket).child(firebaseNode.getthumbnail());
    // Load the image using Glide
    Glide.with(mContext)
            .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
            .load(storageReference)
            .centerCrop()
            .crossFade()
            .into(thumbnailImage);
  }
 }
```

As I say before when I replace the GridLayoutManager with the StaggeredGridLayoutManager, I have all the thumbnails of my list that appears on my emulator. However wneh I use the GridLayoutManager, nothing happens, and I don't have any error in the console, so I'm stuck. Can someone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: kindly try always to post with terminal report, it will be much more conceivable then